# Javascript: How can I search and replace multiple items with matched groups?

Tags: javascript, regex

Say I have a string like

```
"item:(one|two|three), item2:(x|y)"
```

Is there a single regex that could "factor" it into

```
"item:one, item:two, item:three, item2:x, item2:y"
```

Or must I resort to splitting and looping?

If I must split it up then how do I even turn

```
"item:(one|two|three)"
```

into

```
"item:one, item:two, item:three"
```

if the amount of things between the parentheses is variable? Are regexes useless for such a problem?

Comment: Isn't that developing instead of factoring ?

Comment: You'd have to do both, matching and splitting/looping.

Comment: Your question is confusing. Could you give samples of expected input and output?

Comment: @HansThen He did give an example, I think

Comment: Hans, I did. You want more samples?

Comment: Felix, if that is the answer then make it an answer.

Comment: I was not sure whether the examples provided were actual input strings or patterns.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could do it with a callback function:

```
 str = str.replace(/(\w+):\(([^)]*)\)/gi, function(match,item,values)
     {return item + ':' + values.split("|").join(', '+item+':')}
 );
```

For every item, the first parentheses in the regex capture the item's name (i.e `item`) and the second set of (unescaped) parentheses capture the string of all values (i.e `one|two|three`). The latter are then split at `|` and joined together with `, itemname:` and then there is another item name appended to the beginning of the result.

This is probably the easiest way to combine regexes to find your data and split and join to build your new regex. The problem why it is not easier is, that you cannot capture an arbitrary number of consecutive values (`one|two|three`) in different capturing groups. You would only get the last one, if you tried to capture them individually.

Comment: Which parts are unclear? (I have already added some explanation while you wrote your comment ;) )

Comment: Your answer is nice and clear I just have to read through the code and I think you are using some tricks I am not familiar with.

Comment: I like the whole 1-line return statement with the splitting and joining. :)

Comment: @Moss, note that my solution will cause problems if your values can contain closing parentheses. Also note that it allows for letters, digits and underscores as item names (and anything but closing parens for values)